# How to dynamically change navigation bar color on ios15?

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

What worked for years was

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = MY_COLOR
```

but in iOS15 this is not working. There's answers for how to change it on app start, but I need to change it after the nav bar's been shown and without reloading the view controller. This is possible in iOS 14 and older.

Comment: call a reference to your appDelegate, or call a static method from your appDelegate to change this.

Comment: let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

Comment: I don't understand. To clarify I need to be able to change the nav bar background multiple times (maybe even once per second) without loading or reloading the view controller. This was possible until iOS 15 so I want to know if it's possible now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VC you can try adjusting the view.backgroundColor

```
      UINavigationBar?.view.backgroundColor = MY_COLOR
```

Comment: did you see this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420

Comment: Yes, it doesn't help change the nav bar color after it's been shown

Comment: So after it's been shown, you need to change it. Does it set it the first time?

Comment: try UINavigationBar?.view.backgroundColor = .yourColor

Comment: maybe we should modify view property on backgroundColor

Comment: Got it, it's navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = MY_COLOR that fixes it. Put it in the answer and I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: done and done! updated.

Comment: Just a comment that it says `UINavigationBar` doesn't have a member `view` so it has to be `navigationController` instead